# Image displayed partially if in drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: android, image, drawable

I'm displaying an image through an ImageSwitcher with this factory:

```
    view_background.setFactory {
        val imageView = ImageView(this@MainActivity)
        imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
        imageView
    }
```

And I'm displaying correctly this `2341x1246 PNG` 2.55 MB image on a Nexus 5 emulator:

[image]

However, if I use it on Nexus 6, it crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.llovagn.t4r, PID: 4693
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(142936136bytes) bitmap.
```

By putting it in `drawable-xxhdpi` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635904/4480180) answer, it now look like this on both devices:

[image]

Which I something that I don't really want (the first way is the correct one). Why and how can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like the size of the file is too large. Is it a .jpg image?

Answer (score 0):

> 2341x1246 PNG **2.55 MB**
>
> Canvas: **trying to draw too large**(**142936136bytes**) bitmap

This doesn't look like a good approach. Reduce the size of the image and put the image in the `drawable` directory.

It happens because you put the picture inside "drawable-**xxhdpi**". Take a look at the sizes [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152009/4409113).

However, after doing what I suggested, use `FIT_XY` to fit the image:

```
imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
```

You won't need 2.5 MB image in your application. That's pretty too much with that size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228830/4480180) answer, should I resize all to images to be at most `1280x1920`?

Comment: «...in the drawable directory...»
I would suggest drawable-nodpi directory instead (https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html)

Comment: And why the `FIT_XY`?

Comment: @justHelloWorld That depends actually. Will you add tablets support to your app in future? It all depends on the devices you are targeting to use the app. Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element) for screen supports and remember to add them.

Comment: @justHelloWorld From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType): `Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL` Depends on you. Maybe you just want to make the image fit center or fill the x,y. However, `FIT_XY` fills the entire page which is a good choice to use.

Comment: Nope, it's a phone app only now and forever!

Comment: So, `2341x1246` is unnecessary and pretty huge (*Use something like under `1000`* and use online websites to reduce the size). If you add one more image like that with 2.5 MB, users won't like an app with too much size to download.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error try to use as small resolution of image as possible, also the image view should also be small, you could also get OOM on bigger and high res devices.
Best way would be to use a png image on a background view where background can be solid color or gradient. By this way you can use smaller images that might not need to fill the whole screen size.