# What is the benefit having images for different screen sizes when using fixed values in dp

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

During Development I was importing images for different screen sizes like mdpi, hdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi etc.
I had to give image a fixed sized like 240dp x 80dp. then what is the role of importing images of different screen size if I am giving fixed value. it is better if I will import one image with good resolution then use fixed value.
please clear my concept if I am wrong

Comment: "what is the role of importing images of different screen size" -- `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xxhdpi`, and `xxxhdpi` are screen *densities*, not screen *sizes*. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) for more.

Comment: that I already know. Read the question carefully I added a condition that if i am using fixed dp ..if the density is decided which is fixed then why importing dynamic images

Comment: "I added a condition that if i am using fixed dp" -- you are using a fixed *size*. "if the density is decided which is fixed" -- you are using a fixed *size*. `240dp` and `80dp` are *sizes* measured in density-independent pixels (`dp`). Please read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Answer (score 0):

1. When user with `mdpi` device screen starts your program - program will get images from `mdpi` folder of resources. If you have only `xhdpi` images - on his `mdpi` device system will downscale image from `xhdpi` folder 2 times before showing. If image exist only in `mdpi` folder - on `xhdpi` device image will upscale 2 times before showing. Downscaling/upscaling means extra CPU, memory usage and lower performance. When you provide image for all densities system will just show proper image without extra calculations. Check scale coeficients [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28507826/1372866) and link to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)
2. If you provide image for all densities there is also profit in `.apk` size for user.  When you upload `.aab` file ([Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)) to google play (instead of `.apk`) and user installs your app he will download `.apk` file which contains images only for his density (image copies for other denseties will be removed from apk). It means that apk files for `mdpi` users will be much smaller than `.apk` files for `xxhdpi` users.